# Vanishing natural transformation exact triangle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

This question is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215802/vanishing-natural-transformation-and-strong-generator) I asked some time ago. Let $X$ be a **smooth** projective variety of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\omega \in H^{n}(X,K_X)$, $\omega \neq 0$. Let 
$$A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow A[1]$$

be an exact triangle in $D^b(X)$. Assume that the morphism:
$$\mathrm{id}_A \otimes \omega : A \longrightarrow A \otimes K_X[n]$$
vanishes in $\mathrm{Hom}(A,A\otimes K_X[n])$ and that the morphism:
$$\mathrm{id}_B \otimes \omega : B \longrightarrow B \otimes K_X [n]$$
vanishes in $\mathrm{Hom}(B,B\otimes K_X[n])$. I'd like to know if the morphism:
$$\mathrm{id}_C \otimes \omega : C \longrightarrow C \otimes K_X[n]$$
vanishes in $\mathrm{Hom}(C,C\otimes K_X[n])$?

I know that there is no *five lemma* for zero-morphisms and that if this statement is true it is not just a formal consequence of the definition of a triangulated category (see the answer to the question I am referring to in the intro).

On the other hand, seen the very special nature of the involved morphisms, I tought it might be true. Or perhaps this is plain wrong and a counter-example would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose that instead of $Hom(A,A[n])$ you want $Hom(A,A\otimes K_X[n])$ and similarly for $B$ and $C$, right?

Comment: @DenisNardin : of course, you're right! I will edit.

Comment: Do you have any examples of complexes where $\operatorname{id} \otimes\ \omega$ vanishes? I tried to construct some, but so far have been unable to.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Let $X$ be a K3 surface and $i : C \longrightarrow X$ be a smooth curve embedded in $X$. Then one can check that $\omega_X \otimes \mathrm{id}_{i_*(\mathcal{O}_C)} : i_*(\mathcal{O}_C) \longrightarrow i_*(\mathcal{O}_C) [2]$ vanishes.

Comment: If this were true, then the full subcategory of $D^b(X)$ consisting of the objects $A$ for which $\text{id}_A\otimes\omega=0$ would be a triangulated subcategory. Clearly it's also closed under taking summands and taking the tensor product with any other object. So it would be what Thomason calls a thick triangulated $\otimes$-subcategory, and he classified such subcategories in terms of the supports of their objects. Maybe this helps?

Comment: @JeremyRickard : I have had a look at Thomason's paper, may I ask you a question about it? In my setting, it claims the following: let $A \subset D^b(X)$ is a thick tensor triangulated subcategory. Denote by $Y$ the subspace of $X$ which the union of the cohomological supports of objects in $A$. Then Thomason claims that all objects cohomologically supported on $Y$ are in $A$. (to follow)

Comment: Now take $A$ the full subcategory of $D^b(X)$ whose objects have cohomological support supported on **strict** subschemes of $X$. Then $A$ is triangulated, thick anb stable by tensor product with an ample line bundle of $X$. Hence $A$ is triangulated thick $\otimes$-subcategory of $D^b(X)$ in the sense of Thomason.
Clearly the union of the cohomological supports of objects in $A$ is $X$. But all objects cohomologically supported on $X$ are not in $A$.

Is there something I am missing there?

Comment: @Libli Thomason is taking the union scheme-theoretically, so if $X$ is irreducible then the union of all strict subschemes doesn’t contain the generic point of $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think I have an argument which shows that if $\mathrm{id}_{A} \otimes \omega : A \longrightarrow A \otimes K_X[n]$ is zero and $\mathrm{id}_{B} \otimes \omega : B \longrightarrow B \otimes K_X[n]$ is zero then $\mathrm{id}_{C} \otimes \omega : C \longrightarrow C \otimes K_X[n]$ is not necessarily zero. This argument uses crucially the result of Thomason that was brought to my attention by Jeremy Rickard (who I heartily thank for that).

Let $X$ be a K3 surface and let $\mathcal{T}$ be the cone of the natural map:
$$\mathcal{O}_X \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X[2]$$
induced by $\omega$. The object $\mathcal{T}$ has rank $0$ in $D^b(X)$ and one easily computes that $\mathrm{End}(\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{T}) = \mathbb{C}$. Assume that the morphism $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{T}} \otimes \omega : \mathcal{T} \longrightarrow \mathcal{T}[2]$ is not zero. Then it is a generator of $\mathrm{Ext}^2(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{T}) = \mathrm{End}(\mathcal{T})^* = \mathbb{C}$. This is impossible. Indeed, we have $$\mathrm{Trace}(\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{T}} \otimes \omega) = \mathrm{rank}(\mathcal{T}).\omega = 0$$ but Serre duality implies that:
$$\mathrm{Trace} : \mathrm{Ext}^2(\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{T}) \longrightarrow H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$$
is surjective. This shows that $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{T}} \otimes \omega = 0$ in $\mathrm{Ext}^{2}(\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{T})$.

Now, assume that for any exact triangle $A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C$ in $D^b(X)$ such that $\mathrm{id}_{A} \otimes \omega : A \longrightarrow A[2]$ is zero and $\mathrm{id}_{B} \otimes \omega : B \longrightarrow B[2]$ is zero, we have $\mathrm{id}_{C} \otimes \omega : C \longrightarrow C[2]$ is also zero. (I denote this hypothesis by $(*)$).

Then, the subcategory of $D^b(X)$ consisting of objects $S$ such $\mathrm{id}_{S} \otimes \omega$ is zero would be a thick $\otimes$-triangulated subcategory of $D^b(X)$ (see the comment of Jeremy Rickard to the question).

It has been checked that $\mathcal{T}$ is in this category and the cohomological support of $\mathcal{T}$ is $X$. Hence, by Thomason classification of thick $\otimes$-triangulated subcategories of $D^b(X)$, we deduce that for any $S \in D^b(X)$ such that the cohomological support of $S$ is $X$, we have the vanishing of $\mathrm{id}_{S} \otimes \omega : S \longrightarrow S \otimes[2]$. This is clearly absurd and hypothesis $(*)$ is incorrect.